# How to inject @Component in DTO class for reusability in Rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have simple and self-sufficient example below with four Java files. My question is how can I annotate the DTO class with @Component and inject it into controller class for reuse? Simple annotating the *ResponseDto.java* class with that annotation doesn't do anything.

First file is REST controller (*Controller.java*), second file is utility class (*CountriesUtility.java*) containing one list of strings with country codes and one method to check if given argument from the controller, country code, is present in the list of strings in this utility class. Third file is main application file (*DemoForInjectionApplication.java*) for running this Spring application. Last file is simple DTO class (*ResponseDTO.java*) used to create response JSON.

This code for POST request at "http://localhost:8080/controller/required_fields?country_code=PL" responds with `{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": "Correct country!"
}` and for POST request at "http://localhost:8080/controller/required_fields?country_code=NOSUCHCOUNTRY" responds with `{
    "status": "Error",
    "data": ""
}`

**Controller.java**

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("controller")
public class Controller {

  @PostMapping(value = "/required_fields", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
  public @ResponseBody ResponseDto requiredFields(@RequestParam(name = "country_code") final String countryCode) {
    /* How can I annotate the DTO class with @Component and inject it into this class for reuse? */
    final ResponseDto responseDto;
    responseDto = new CountriesCurrenciesUtility().isValidCountryAndCurrency(countryCode);
    return responseDto;
  }

}
```

**CountriesUtility.java**

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CountriesCurrenciesUtility {

  private static final List<String> COUNTRIES = Arrays.asList("BE", "GR", "RE", "PL");

  public ResponseDto isValidCountryAndCurrency(final String countryCode) {
    ResponseDto dto = new ResponseDto();

    if (COUNTRIES.contains(countryCode)) {
      dto.setData("Correct country!");
      dto.setStatus("OK");
    } else {
      dto.setData("");
      dto.setStatus("Error");
    }

    return dto;
  }
}
```

**DemoForInjectionApplication.java**

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoForInjectionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoForInjectionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ResponseDTO.java**

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ResponseDto {
  /**
   * Status of the request.
   */
  @JsonProperty()
  private String status;

  /**
   * Data of the request.
   */
  @JsonProperty()
  private String data;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ResponseDto{" +
      "status='" + status + '\'' +
      ", data='" + data + '\'' +
      '}';
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ResponseDto that = (ResponseDto) o;
    return Objects.equals(status, that.status) &&
      Objects.equals(data, that.data);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(status, data);
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

**pom.xml** 
Just in case somebody would like to run it locally, you will need to create packages manually. This is simple pom file, generated using Spring Initializr with "*Rest Repositories WEB*" and "*Spring Web*" dependencies with Java 11.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.examplead</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-for-injection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-for-injection</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It is a missconcept, do not make managed your model and transfer objects. If you want to reuse those two instance (ok and nok cases) just instantiate them on startup or first use, and return with them.

Comment: @zlaval what if I would make CountriesUtility. isValidCountryAndCurrency(final String countryCode) method class static? Would it be OK for reusing it, as I will use it several times later in the code?

Comment: you can do that, or you can make the class to bean and inject it. Those two can work of course.

Comment: @zlaval I will make class CountriesUtility a Bean and how could I inject it inside the controller, using Autowired? Autowired seems to be not the best option according to the Internet and Intellij pop up. How else I could inject my CountriesUtility into my controller?

Comment: If it is a bean, use autowired. You can use setter (optional dependenny => aggregation connection) or constructor injection (requiered dependency => composition connection). Field injection is the easiest, but not the best practice, because testing is harder.

Comment: DTOs are never used for injection. They are used for data transfer from one layer to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** *Data Transfer Objects are not meant for injection. They are used for transferring data from one layer to another. The response through DTOs may be same or different based on the APIs present in your application. So, it is better to create instance of DTO when required to send data from one layer to another.*

You can do `@Component` on `ResponseDto`.

**But this is a bad design and may lead to some unwanted response.**

**So, it is not recommend to annotate DTO with** `@Component` **based on the working definition of DTO.**

You can follow this simple design.

Modify **ResponseDTO.java** and keep in the package `com.examplead.demoforinjection.dto`:

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ResponseDto implements Serializable {

  /**
   * default serial version ID
   */  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

  /**
   * Status of the request.
   */
  private String status;

  /**
   * Data of the request.
   */
  private String data;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ResponseDto{" +
      "status='" + status + '\'' +
      ", data='" + data + '\'' +
      '}';
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

}
```

Modify **CountriesCurrenciesUtility.java** and keep in the package `com.examplead.demoforinjection.utility` :

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection.utility;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.examplead.demoforinjection.dto.ResponseDto; 

public final class CountriesCurrenciesUtility {

  private static final List<String> COUNTRIES = Arrays.asList("BE", "GR", "RE", "PL");

  public static ResponseDto isValidCountryAndCurrency(final String countryCode) {
    ResponseDto dto = new ResponseDto();

    if (COUNTRIES.contains(countryCode)) {
      dto.setData("Correct country!");
      dto.setStatus("OK");
    } else {
      dto.setData("No data found.");
      dto.setStatus("Error");
    }

    return dto;
  }
}
```

Modify **Controller.java** and keep in the package `com.examplead.demoforinjection.controller` :

```
package com.examplead.demoforinjection.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.examplead.demoforinjection.dto.ResponseDto;
import com.examplead.demoforinjection.utility.CountriesCurrenciesUtility; 

@RestController
@RequestMapping("controller")
public class Controller {

  @PostMapping(value = "/required_fields", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> requiredFields(@RequestParam(name = "country_code") final String countryCode) {
    ResponseDto responseDto = CountriesCurrenciesUtility.isValidCountryAndCurrency(countryCode);
    if(responseDto.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
      return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDto>(responseDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDto>(responseDto, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }

}
```

Note : `@RestController` includes both `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller`. So, you don't need to use `@ResponseBody` separately.

Comment: @nanomader Is it helpful.

Comment: This answer is correct as ResponseDto should not be annotated with Component. Just wanted to add that the reason the Component does not work specifically in the example is because it it instantiated directly in isValidCountryAndCurrency and is not a Spring managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer states, it's not a recommended way of doing things. However, there is a way of injecting dependencies into unmanaged classes (created with "new" operator).

There is `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable` annotation, which is meant for that.

Reference:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects

Dependending on a scenario and architectural approach, it can do great things. `Anemic domain objects` is considered anti-pattern by some.